# Error showing :Ethernet Cable unplugged in Ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: 14.04, networking, dual-boot, ethernet

I have been using dual boot OS one is windows 10 and another Os is Ubuntu 14.04. in windows10 ethernet working perfectly fine.but when I using ubuntu it showing ethernet cable is unplugged. I have changed the LAN wire but no use. am kind of new to ubuntu please help me? I have read similar questions here but no solution given by anyone.
System Information:

Dell Vostro 3000 series;
3gb Ram
500gb hardisk

Comment: Please edit the question to include the results of `lspci`

Answer (score 0):

I had this kind of trouble, I'm not sure is the best way but it use to help doing :

`sudo ifconfig eth0 down`

`sudo ifconfig eth0 up`

depending on your system "eth0" may be something else, just have a look whith

`sudo ifconfig`

This will show you all your interfaces

hope this help !